# Jsf validate datatable each row content using custom validator

Tags: jsf

I want to validate each content of following datatable.which display set of urls.

```
<h:form id="dfCompose" styleClass="form-horizontal">
    <h:dataTable styleClass="attachPanel" id="attmsg" width="100%" value="#{ForumTool.attachments}" >

        .....................
        ........................

        <f:validator validatorId="forumAndTopicUrlContentValidator" /> 
        <f:attribute name="validationItemLabel" value="#{msgs.cdfm_att}" /> 

    <h:dataTable/>

<h:form/>
```

I have written a custom validator to validate jsf datatable content.
import java.util.List;

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

    public class ForumAndTopicUrlContentValidator implements Validator{

        private static final String MESSAGECENTER_BUNDLE = "org.sakaiproject.api.app.messagecenter.bundle.Messages";

        @Override
        public void validate(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
                throws ValidatorException {

            List inputValue = (List) arg2;

        }

    }
```

but when the page with datatable loads

it failed with following runtime exception

> Stacktrace:
>       at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.SkinnableCharonPortal.forwardTool(SkinnableCharonPortal.java:1508)
>   caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred
>   processing JSP page /jsp/dfCompose.jsp at line 157
>
> 154:                                  155:
>   156:                                  157:
>    158:
>                                  159:                                  160:
>
> Stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
>   caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable cannot be cast to
>   javax.faces.component.EditableValueHolder
>       at javax.faces.webapp.ValidatorTag.doStartTag(ValidatorTag.java:130)
>       at org.apache.jsp.jsp.dfCompose_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fvalidator_005f2(dfCompose_jsp.java:1627)
>       at org.apache.jsp.jsp.dfCompose_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fdataTable_005f0(dfCompose_jsp.java:1100)
>       at org.apache.jsp.jsp.dfCompose_jsp._jspService(dfCompose_jsp.java:379)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338

How can i validate jsf datatable content by custom validator?

Comment: @ perissf  all necessary imports are available

Comment: @BalusC can you help on this?

Comment: @ perissf There are no issues in namespace.issue is this "caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.EditableValueHolder at javax.faces.webapp.ValidatorTag.doStartTag(ValidatorTag.java:130"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169774/discussion-between-niranga-sandaruwan-and-perissf).

Comment: check the validators that come with OmniFaces and read http://ovaraksin.blogspot.nl/2012/11/validate-unique-input-values-within.html